# How to disable "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer" message from showing?

Tags: windows, registry, error-messaging

I Develop a medical device that runs Windows 10 Ent. 1809. since this is a medical device, must Windows Explorer and other Windows settings need to be restricted from the user that operates this device.
So I Had to turn change most of the Registry values in

```
Computer\HKEY_USERS\Medical\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

The problem that I am facing is this annoying "This operation has been canceled due to restrictions in effect on this computer" message, which I DO NOT want my user to see.

[image]

How do I prevent this message from showing?

I basically searched all over the internet for a solution. But I couldn't find any information on the matter, except on chat from Microsoft forum which, surprise.. surprise..., was not helpful.

Comment: [Kiosk mode?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/kiosk-mode/kiosk-mode)

Comment: Also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app).

Comment: Hey there.  Have you had a look at Kiosk mode yet?  Seems like it would be ideal for your specific scenario.